# Validate string as date and convert to Joda DateTime

Tags: jodatime

I want to convert a string to joda DateTime in the form of "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss". The string should be in one of two formats,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" or "yyyy-MM-dd", although it is user input, so I may need to kick it back if it isn't in either format. How can I check for the case where no timestamp is present and append 00:00:00 to it? Below is my code for the case where the full date and time are given.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    DateTime formattedDate= formatter.parseDateTime(dateString);
```

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you check for the length of the string ?

```
if ( dateString.length() == "yyyy-MM-dd".length() )
    dateString += "00:00:00";
```

Comment: I have updated my question to be more clear. The strings should be in those formats, but I will need to do some additional validation to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### ISO 8601

Your input string nearly complies with the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. To comply, replace that <sup>SPACE</sup> with a `T`. The java.time classes use standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern. If the input is of the date-only type, the `replace` has no effect.

```
String input = "2017-01-23 12:34:56".replace( " " , "T" ) ;  // Replace SPACE with `T` to comply with ISO 8601.
String input = "2017-01-23".replace( " " , "T" ) ;  // Has no effect.
```

### Various inputs

To handle both the date-only or date-time inputs, either [test for length](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length--) or attempt a parse and trap for exception.

```
if( input.length() == 10 ) {
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input ) ;
} else {
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
}
```

### Zone/Offset

Note that a `LocalDateTime` purposely lacks any offset-from-UTC & time zone. If your situation is known to intend either offset or zone, assign to create an `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime z = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).